# ITM reporting the different situations

Tags: monitoring, tivoli

I am trying to get a report on ITM 6.2.1 regarding each equipment and situations running with some of the configuration info.

I need to list each equipment, each situation, formula and the system command with the mail send. Is there a way to get this info without having to go manually into each equipment, situation, etc?

Example:

Equip: equip01 
Agent: LinuxOS
Situations: LINUX_FILE_SIZE, LINUX_UNIX_FS_CRITICAL, etc
Formula: FILE: '/local/file.err' SIZE: !=0,000
Action: System command: usr/bin/mail oper@mail.com

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to create a report regarding all the situations running at the moment. this should include the situation name, managed system, formula and system command (because of the mailing info).

I found the Situation_History table from where I have obtained the system and situation. I was wondering where can I get the rest of the info (without going manually into each situation in the TEP).

Any help or comment is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many ways to do this, but I would look into some shell scripting using tacmd commands, like "tacmd listsit -m AGENT" and "tacmd viewsit -s SITUATION" you can automate the work by combining the outputs of these commands and create a report that way.

Also, there is a cool tool called "ITMSUPER" that connects to you ITM environment through SOAP calls and creates really useful reports about the entire environment, you should definitely take a look:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/home/wiki/Use%20ITMSUPER%20to%20Solve%20ITM%20Issues/page/Some%20Useful%20Examples%20of%20ITMSUPER%20for%20Beginners?lang=en

Comment: This is looking good. I'm having this issue though, when I list the situations I only get columns 'Type' and 'Name' but no status. I am supposed to report the ones that are running atm.